# rangeslider thumb behind on track for firefox browser only..how to fix it ? my code given below

Tags: css, html

hi am using two values of range slider itz fine to working on chrome and safari but mozilla browser not support am try my best can't solve this problem

```css
input[type=range]:nth-child(1)::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index:999;
}
input[type=range]:nth-child(2)::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: green;
 
}
input[type=range]{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="20"/>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="90"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

See here:http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html

`::-moz-range-thumb` to FIREFOX

`::-webkit-slider-runnable-track` to CHROME, SAFARI, OPERA

`::-ms-thumb` to INTERNET EXPLORER 10 +

**And do not use:**

```
input[type=range]{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```css
input[type=range]:nth-child(1)::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index:999;
}
input[type=range]:nth-child(2)::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: green;
 
}

 input[type=range]:nth-child(1)::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index:999;
}
 input[type=range]:nth-child(2)::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-color: green;
 
}
input[type=range]:nth-child(1)::-ms-thumb{
  background-color: blue;
  z-index:999;
}
input[type=range]:nth-child(2)::-ms-thumb {
  background-color: green;
 
}
```

```html
<input class="range1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="20"/>
<input class="range2" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="90"/>
```

Comment: hey... tell me for more help

Comment: am refer this dude....but slider thumb behind of the track how to solve it? i want both thumb are infront of track

Comment: try do not use `input[type=range]{
  position:absolute;
}`

Comment: tell me if it help you

Comment: only IE issue i think -moz-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
         -o-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;  this elements not working

Comment: Removing position: relative or absolute fix the overlap for me

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="range"] {
 pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb 
{
 z-index: 10; 
 pointer-events: all;
}
```

Comment: Hi Paulina, welcome to StackOverflow. When you answer a question please do not only provide the code but some explanation or link to the documentation as well. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer